# IndexOutOfBoundsException without accessing array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to implement Merge Sort but I keep getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` and I can't figure out the reason.

I have debugged my program and at no point in this function am I accessing the array with an invalid index. The line causing the exception is also unrelated to the array `a`, which is the one throwing the exception.

So here is the function throwing the exception:

```
private static int[] merge(int[] a, int[] b){
    int[] res = new int[a.length + b.length];
    int ia = 0;
    int ib = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while(ia < a.length || ib < b.length){
        if(ia < a.length && a[ia] < b[ib]) {
            res[i] = a[ia];
            ia++;
            i++; //this is the line causing the exception
        }
        else {
            res[i] = b[ib];
            ib++;
            i++;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Am I missing some Java specific behavior? and if so how can I work around this issue?

I am also aware that I shouldn't use arrays in java anymore but the class I am in forbids any other container.

Comment: Change the first conditional to `if(ia < a.length && (ib >= b.length || a[ia] < b[ib])) {`.

Comment: If you do a copy of a + b, then why not using System.arraycopy instead? (the IndexOutOfBoundsException is due to bad array access, the line mismatch is due to your debugger not being in phase with your code)?

Comment: @NoDataFound I am not allowed to use arraycopy either. I also looked into the issue debugging line for line and the value of `a[ia]` was successfully copied into `red[i]`. It really only threw the exception in this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this condition:

```
ia < a.length || ib < b.length
```

since `ia` and `ib` change values independently, one of them may be equal to its corresponding array length and not the other, but the condition will be `true` and the loop will be executed. 
Then in the first `if` this condition:

```
 a[ia] < b[ib]
```

will throw the error. 
So the condition must be changed to:

```
ia < a.length && ib < b.length
```

and after the loop all the remaining items of 1 of the 2 arrays will be inserted in `res` with a `for` loop:

```
private static int[] merge(int[] a, int[] b){
    int[] res = new int[a.length + b.length];
    int ia = 0;
    int ib = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while(ia < a.length && ib < b.length){
        if(a[ia] < b[ib]) {
            res[i] = a[ia];
            ia++;
            i++; 
        }
        else {
            res[i] = b[ib];
            ib++;
            i++;
        }
    }

    if (ia < a.length) {
        for (int k = ia; k < a.length; k++) {
            res[i] = a[k];
            i++;
        }
    }
    if (ib < b.length) {
        for (int k = ib; k < b.length; k++) {
            res[i] = b[k];
            i++;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Test case:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {1, 4, 5, 8, 10};
    int[] b = {2, 3, 7, 9};
    int[] c = merge(a, b);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c));
}
```

prints:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

but your code throws an error.
Of course this is **a solution based on your code**.  
Merging two sorted arrays can be implemented in other more efficient ways.

Comment: Ok now I am starting to question my environment, I did what you wrote but I still get an error in the first cycle in the same line as before. Could it have to do with the JDK or anything else? 'Merge sort can be implemented in other more efficient ways' ***sigh*** don't tell me that, I am not allowed to use recursion, default containers or anything really. It is also only the subroutine, so there are some parts missing.

Comment: Do you mean that my code crashes in the above test case?

Comment: If it crashes for another test case, just post it in a comment and I will test it. Nobody's perfect.

Comment: ok sorry never mind, I just looked at your code in debug and it was only IntelliJ's observation object which threw an exception. Your code is running somewhat fine, I am still getting nullptr exceptions but I think I'll be able to figure those out.

Comment: I just tested my code and the nullptr exceptions are caused by the parameters. your code runs perfectly fine I am just passing empty arrays somewhere.

Comment: I tested my code for empty arrays and it works. If you mean `null` arrays then it's another case.

Comment: oh, right. I am passing `null` arrays not empty ones, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

The instruction `i++` can't cause `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. You are mot likely debugging different code in editor comparing to the code which is running in the JVM (e.g. new code was edited but not build). Rebuild your Java code and ensure that you have the same code visible in the editor and running in the JVM so the line numbers are aligned.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I tried every option there is in IntelliJs build menu and also restarted the ide but it still throws the same exception in the same line.

Comment: @jaklh you can *Rebuild the project*, also can look into the answer by me to verify in your code the chances of a possible scenario unhandled.

Answer (score 0):

I think changing `if` condition should solve the problem.

**from:-**

```
if(ia < a.length && a[ia] < b[ib]) {
```

**to:-**

```
if (ia < a.length) {
```

**Failed Test case before code fix:-**

```
int[] a = {2, 3, 4};
int[] b = {0, 1};
```

I have tested with other test cases like:-

1. Array a is smaller than array b (i.e. array size)
2. Array a is bigger than array b
3. Array a is empty and array b has elements
4. Array a has elements and array b is empty
5. Both array a and b are empty

All seems to be working fine.

Comment: Thanks but I actually can't do this because I only want to append `a[ia]` to `res` if it is smaller than `b[ib]` otherwise I want to append `b[ib]` to `res`.

Comment: Then, both array 'a' and 'b' should have equal number of elements and you are actually comparing the values of elements in each index (value of index 0 is compared to 0, index 1 is compared to 1). So, if the size of array 'a' is smaller than array 'b', then you will get IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: They can actually also have different lengths so for instance I have `a = {1, 2, 4}` and `b = {3}` I want the result to be `res = {1, 2, 3, 4}`.

Answer (score 0):

Without commenting on why your IDE says the problem is on that line, the *actual* problem is that you aren't handling the case where `ib` moves beyond the end of the `b` array before `ia` moves beyond the end of the `a` array.

Change the first conditional to:

```
if(ia < a.length && (ib >= b.length || a[ia] < b[ib])) {
```

which avoids the evaluation of `b[ib]` in the case that `ib >= b.length`.

Although, personally I think a clearer way to do this would be:

```
while(ia < a.length && ib < b.length){
  // Merge the arrays
}
while(ia < a.length) {
  // Append remaining elements from a
}
while(ib < b.length) {
  // Append remaining elements from b
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This while loop `while(ia < a.length || ib < b.length)` condition is unsafe, as it allows to get inside it while either counter `ia` or `ib` may have crossed the length of either array which may cause `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. You can make the code simpler to something like this,

```
private static int[] merge(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int[] res = new int[a.length + b.length];
    int ia = 0;
    int ib = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        if (ia < a.length && ib < b.length) { // if both arrays have elements
            if (a[ia] < b[ib]) {
                res[i] = a[ia++]; // copy element from a as it is smaller than b to res array
            } else {
                res[i] = b[ib++]; // copy element from b as it is smaller than a to res array
            }
        } else if (ia < a.length) {
            res[i] = a[ia++]; // a array still have some elements left so just copy from a to res array
        } else {
            res[i] = b[ib++]; // b array still have some elements left so just copy from b to res array
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Ok I understand what your code is doing and I can't find any reason for it not to work. I copied pasted it and but I still get the same exception, this time in line: `res[i] = a[ia++];`(in the first cycle) for `a={3}` and `b={5}`.

Comment: I don't know how you checked but my program works perfect for `a={3}` and `b={5}` Check it with this. No exception of any sort.  `public static void main(String[] args) {
  int out[] = merge(new int[] { 3 }, new int[] { 5 });
  IntStream.of(out).forEach(System.out::println);
 }`